# How to share link to Facebook Messenger app in iOS (Objective-C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-share, fbsdkmessengersharekit

I'm using fb ios sdk for sharing link to people connected on fb messenger.
There is no way I can find to share link on Messenger app.

FBSDKMessengerSharer class only can share audio, video and image to Messenger. How can I open Messenger app with initiating particular link? Please help me soon.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share a link you have to install `FBSDKShareKit` and not `FBSDKMessengerShareKit`.

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = URL(string: "http://google.com")
content.imageURL = URL(string: "http://google.com/image.png")
content.contentTitle = "Some link title"

let messageDialog = FBSDKMessageDialog()
messageDialog.shareContent = content
messageDialog.show()
```

Take a look here for more options: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios

Answer (score 0):

Your are right. My understanding as well is, the API has no support at this point beyond media sharing to messenger using `FBSDKMessengerShareButton`. I scanned through this and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/reference and there is nothing.

If your URL is GIF or WebP you can try using the `sourceURL` attribute of `FBSDKMessengerShareOptions`.

Thanks

Comment: But how do they achieve it in News app (system app)? I could successfully shared news article in Messenger. I don't know how they do it.

Comment: do you think FBSDKMessengerURLHandler is of any use in this scenario?

Comment: As per the documentation, No. But let me spike it and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

if you use swift pages facebook same me,and don't know to share link into Messenger app will try this

1. add lib facebook or  swift pages facebook in you project
2. write code to open

- 

```
let content = ShareLinkContent()

    content.contentURL = URL(string: linkShare)!

    let messageDialog = MessageDialog()
    messageDialog.shareContent = content
    messageDialog.show()
```

done.

### try run code.

### ** if you can't share link try check below picture

[image]

1.you will see url fail

2. copy url in your log (my log is "fb-messenger-share-api").

3.add link in info.plist
[image]